# Member function definition outside of class body results in error

Tags: c++, templates, stack, singly-linked-list

I am pretty new to the concept of templates. Am I missing something?

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

template < class T>
class Stack{
private:
  struct node {
    T data;
    node* next;
  };
  node * top;
  //node* getNewNode(T num);
};

//template <class T>
//(node*)Stack<T> :: getNewNode(T num){
//    node *    temp = new node;
//      temp->data = num;
//      temp->next = NULL;
//      return temp;
//  }

#endif
```

When I uncomment the function getNewNode and commend the corresponding statement to getNewNode function, complier gives error like
Why is my function getNewNode not working as expected. Where did I go wrong?

```
Error   7   error C2470: 'Stack<T>::getNewNode' : looks like a function
definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent
body    c:\users\nitinjose\documents\visual studio
2010\projects\templatequeue\templatequeue\stack.h   26  1   TemplateQueue
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
does not support default-int    c:\users\nitinjose\documents\visual
studio
2010\projects\templatequeue\templatequeue\stack.h   26  1   TemplateQueue
Error   5   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier
'num'   c:\users\nitinjose\documents\visual studio
2010\projects\templatequeue\templatequeue\stack.h   26  1   TemplateQueue
```

Comment: template function return types are no different than regular c++, if you'd made a function with (node *)getnode(int num) the compiler would have barked at you just as it does with templates, Troubadour is absolutely correct in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of the return value is wrong. Try this

```
template <class T>
typename Stack<T>::node* Stack<T> :: getNewNode(T num){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a member function outside of a class body changes the rules for what names are accessible at that point slightly. In your case the compiler has no idea what `node` is. You need to tell him that the `node*` is actually in the class `Stack<T>`, e.g. `typename Stack<T>::node`. The `typename` is necessary here, because node is a dependent name.